# MySQL table JOIN - not working correctly

Tags: mysql

I want to join two tables. Display table A with the corresponding values from table B.

TableA

```
        ID   |   NAMES
        1    |   jan
        2    |   san
        3    |   tani
        4    |   mike
```

TableB

```
       ID   |   VALUE
       1    |   groen
       1    |   geel
       1    |   oranja
       2    |   groen
```

QUERY

```
       SELECT * FROM TableA a LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.id = b.id
```

OUTPUT

```
      1 - jan - groen
      1 - jan - geel
      1 - jan - oranja
      2 - san - groen
      3 - tani
      4 - mike
```

REQUIRED OUTPUT

```
      1 - jan - groen, geel, oranja
      2 - san - groen
      3 - tani
      4 - mike
```

I have changed the query to every possible thing (left join, left inner join, left outer join, right join, right inner join, right outer join, full join, join) in every possible order (select TableA.id, TableA.names TableB.id...etc.) If I understand the joining correctly, the type of join I am looking for is INNER LEFT JOIN - to display TableA with the corresponding values of TableB.

I am working with MySQL 5.6

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in your application code. There's no such thing as an INNER LEFT JOIN, so I would question your understanding of JOINs. That said, the query you have used is the one I would use.

Comment: Please don't question my understanding of JOINs in SQL - the reason why I am asking is because I do not know

Comment: It was a direct response to the statement 'if I understand the joining correctly'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query

```
SELEct a.id,a.name, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(b.name)name 
 FROM a left JOIN b ON (a.id = b.id)
 GROUP BY a.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following:

```
<?php

/*
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablea;

CREATE TABLE tablea
(ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,NAME VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO tablea VALUES
(1,'jan'),
(2,'san'),
(3,'tani'),
(4,'mike');


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tableb;

CREATE TABLE tableb
(ID   INT NOT NULL
,VALUE VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(id,value)
);

INSERT INTO tableb VALUES
(1,'groen'),
(1,'geel'),
(1,'oranja'),
(2,'groen');

SELECT a.id
     , a.name
     , b.value
  FROM tablea a
  LEFT
  JOIN tableb b
    ON b.id = a.id
 ORDER
    BY id
     , value;
+----+------+--------+
| ID | NAME | value  |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | jan  | geel   |
|  1 | jan  | groen  |
|  1 | jan  | oranja |
|  2 | san  | groen  |
|  3 | tani | NULL   |
|  4 | mike | NULL   |
+----+------+--------+
*/

require('path/to/connection/stateme.nts');

$query = "
SELECT a.id
     , a.name
     , b.value
  FROM tablea a
  LEFT
  JOIN tableb b
    ON b.id = a.id
 ORDER
    BY id
     , value;
";

$result = mysqli_query($db,$query) or die(mysqli_error());

$old_array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

$old_array[] = $row;

}


$new_array = array();

foreach ($old_array as $row) {
   $new_array[$row['id']]['name'] = $row['name'];
   $new_array[$row['id']]['value'][] = $row['value'];
}

$new_array = array_values($new_array); // reindex


print_r($new_array);

?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => jan
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => geel
                    [1] => groen
                    [2] => oranja
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => san
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => groen
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => tani
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => mike
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>
                )

        )

)
```